# Не отображает изображение pygame

Tags: python, python-2.x, pygame

Просто открывается окно с черным экраном. В чем проблема?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()


background = pygame.image.load('1.jpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(background.get_size())
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinahoy")
mainLoop = True



while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В майнлупе забыли добавить функцию перерисовки поверхности экрана `pygame.display.flip`. Без нее на каждой итерации цикла все рассчитывается, но ничего на поверхность экрана не выводится. Выглядеть будет так:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

background = pygame.image.load('1.jpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(background.get_size())
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinahoy")
mainLoop = True

while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Подробнее смотреть [в официальной документации](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip). Ну и это так же объясняется в [первом уроке](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html) там же.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()


background = pygame.image.load('1.jpg')
print(background.get_size())
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(background.get_size())
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dinahoy")
mainLoop = True



while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            mainLoop = False


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что изображения нужно отрисовывать в главном цикле. Ибо вы нарисовали картинку, а потом обновляете экран, и не рисуете ее повторно.